# Дочерний элемент не отображает собственную opacity, если она больше родительского

Tags: css, opacity

```css
.parent {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Атрибут: `opacity: 1;` у дочернего элемента, браузер будто игнорирует, при этом если установить, к примеру, 0.2 (меньше, чем у родителя) - отображает.

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/w0vzb142/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `rgba(n, n, n, n)` для фонового цвета, вместо применения `opacity` ко всему блоку и потомкам:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  /* opacity: 0.3; */
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 1);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  /* opacity: 1; */
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

body { background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png'); }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```